# jQuery Function Chained Effect

Tags: jquery, html

I need to create a jQuery function which contains a chained effect to slide all of the elements of my page around repeatedly whilst changing the background.

I would like to add a button as well that will execute the function when clicked and one to stop it.

I've managed to create a button that changes the background when clicked and slides all the elements up and down. However, I'm not sure how to slide all the elements to the left and right as well and I'm not sure how to do so repeatedly.

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
 $("#chainedEffect").click(function() {
  $("*").css("background", "linear-gradient(to right, crimson, lightcoral").animate({right: "500px"}, 1000).animate({left: "500px"}, 1000).slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000);
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Task</title>
 <!-- CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
 <!-- jQuery -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="task.js"></script>
 <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5ed383133a.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Change paragraph styling -->
<p id="changeStyle">Create a jQuery function which changes only a single paragraph's styling.</p>

<!-- Fade out any object that is clicked on. -->
<img src="images/img-fade.jpg" alt="Image Fade">

<!-- Drop down menu -->
<ul class="menu">
 <li>
  <div>
   <a href="#">Item 1 <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="dropDownMenu">
   <li>Item 1.1</li>
   <li>Item 1.2</li>
   <li>Item 1.3</li>
   <li>Item 1.4</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div>
   <a href="#">Item 2 <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="dropDownMenu">
   <li>Item 2.1</li>
   <li>Item 2.2</li>
   <li>Item 2.3</li>
   <li>Item 2.4</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div>
   <a href="#">Item 3 <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="dropDownMenu">
   <li>Item 3.1</li>
   <li>Item 3.2</li>
   <li>Item 3.3</li>
   <li>Item 3.4</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>

<!-- Chained effect -->
<button id="chainedEffect">Chained Effect</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I am fairly new to jQuery so I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Try taking a look at CSS animations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction - you could bundle your animations into a single CSS rule and apply that to the `body` element instead.

Comment: I would try that. However, this is for a task and I am required to use jQuery specifically.

Comment: I see. Try searching for "jQuery slide element to the side" and see if you can incorporate what you find into your code. As for making it repeat, check out `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. Side note: using the wildcard selector `$("*")` will have performance issues if there are many elements.